# Transform PSQL rows into arrays?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, csv

I have a postgresql database containing a table that looks something like this simplified example:

```
Name  Pets            Hobbies
Jhon  Dog, Cat, Cat   Music
Jane  Dog             Sports, Music
Dan   Dog, Turtle     Reading, Sports, VideoGames
Lia   Cat, Cat        VideoGames, Sports
```

As you can see, in this example I have 3 columns, 2 of them containg some strings separated by commas. What I would like to do is to get that values into arrays, so if I do something like:

```
SELECT
    Name,
    Pets,
    Hobbies
FROM
    examples_table;
```

I get an output like this (having the contents of the rows with multiple values in arrays):

```
Name  Pets              Hobbies
Jhon  {Dog, Cat, Cat}   {Music}
Jane  {Dog}             {Sports, Music}
Dan   {Dog, Turtle}     {Reading, Sports, VideoGames}
Lia   {Cat, Cat}        {VideoGames, Sports}
```

So that way I can access to the contents I want easily (for example, if I want to access who has Cat as Pets). I know this is a possible thing to do on PostgreSQL, but i don't know how to do it (also I'm currently working on psql version 12 on an Ubuntu device). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The built-in `string_to_array()` will handle this for you:

```
select name,
       string_to_array(pets, ', ') as pets,
       string_to_array(hobbies, ', ') as hobbies
  from examples_table;
```

If you want to change the table in-place:

```
alter table examples_table
  alter column pets type text[]
    using string_to_array(pets, ', '),
  alter column hobbies type text[]
    using string_to_array(hobbies, ', ');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! just another question, does this converts the rows permanently to arrays? Because that's what I want (because later i will have to share my database with other users and it would be useful for them too to have the data stored in arrays)

Comment: @DavidMasnouSánchez  The query does not change the table.  I have updated my answer to include an `alter table` for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
name, 
regexp_split_to_array(pets,', '),
regexp_split_to_array(hobbies,', ') from example
```

or

```
select 
name, 
string_to_array(pets,', '), 
string_to_array(hobbies,', ') 
from example
```

**EDIT**
for your comment's requirement run this:

```
update  example set 
       pets=regexp_split_to_array(pets, ', ') ,
       hobbies=regexp_split_to_array(hobbies, ', ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! just another question, does this converts the rows permanently to arrays? Because that's what I want (because later i will have to share my database with other users and it would be useful for them too to have the data stored in arrays)

Comment: added your requirement in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! really appreciated your answer!

Comment: @AkhileshMishra  The `update` statement will not work.  The column datatypes will remain `text` with the `text` representation of the `text[]` arrays.  You have to do `alter table. . . alter column` to change those columns to type `text[]`.